# Powershell - When an object is placed on the pipeline, can it be used again later?

Tags: powershell

I have a collection of objects which I am trying to return multiple sets of data from. Each time I want to select one of the properties of the object and sort it uniquely.

The problem I'm getting is that I only get results the first time I use the collection. This leads me to wonder whether the objects are being "consumed" when I put them on the pipeline.

To illustrate with an example:

```
$results = getMyCollectionOfObjects

$results | select-object property1 | sort-object -unique property1
$results | select-object property2 | sort-object -unique property2
$results | select-object property3 | sort-object -unique property3
```

As far as I can tell this should result in 3 distinct lists of all the possible values for each of the three properties.

However for me it's like the $results value is being "used up" the first time it is selected from.

Is this the case and what should I do instead?

Hope this is clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "used up"?

Comment: @ShawnMelton I mean it no longer contains the list of objects it started with

Comment: What does `getMyCollectionOfObjects` do?

Comment: @manojlds - for the purposes of the question it doesn't really matter as long as it returns 1 or more objects of the same type. The question also implies each object has at least 3 properties called property1, property2 and property3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how it rolls... you have to *explicitly* pipe them to Out-Default to get rid of that odd behavior. Otherwise it will try to display property1 for 2nd and 3rd set too. You removed it from $results, so it comes back blank.

HTH
Bartek

Comment: so are you saying that if I added "| Out-Default" to the end of the three lines this will make it work as I want it?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I'm saying. Actually... You do not need it for last one. But if you want to "flush" output after first two - push them to Out-Default.

Comment: That does seem to do the job, thanks. Now I just have to make sure I understand the reason that it works that way (probably resources and performance but it still seems inconsistent to me), but that's a different question. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

So this had me tripped up and scratching my head or a minute as well. The answer it turns out is really quite simple: the Select-Object cmdlet returns an object of type `Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`. That is then passed down the pipeline to following two selects, but since there are no longer any matching properties (they were discarded from the first select) - nothing is output. Consider the following example:

```
# declare an array and populate it
$results = @()
$results = $results + (New-Object PSobject -Property @{
P1 = "One"
P2 = "Two"
P3 = "Three"
})
$results = $results + (New-Object PSobject -Property @{
P1 = "Uno"
P2 = "Dos"
P3 = "Tres"
})

$results | select P1
$results | select P2
$results | select P3
```

As you described, I was only getting output from the first select. I them took the suggestion from BartekB to put `| Out-Default` at the end of each line and it started working. I investigated further by replacing that with `| Get-Member` to view the object the was being placed on the pipeline:

```
$results | select -Property P1 | get-member

    TypeName: Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition                    
----        ----------   ----------                    
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method       type GetType()                
ToString    Method       string ToString()             
P1          NoteProperty System.String P1=One
```

In a nutshell, the Out-Default is required to actually force it to display on the console instead of passing it along to the next statement. It would seem this behavior is implied upon completing a statement in the interactive shell, but behaves a bit differently when fully scripted.

Comment: `Select-Object` will only return an object of type `PSCustomObject` when the `-Property` parameter is used. If only the `-First`, `-Last`, `-Skip`, `-Index` or `-Unique` parameters are used you will get the original object type back.